# How to publish slack notification from jenkins to multiple channels based on certain condition

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

For example, My job runs on multiple environment. One for Prod and another for test
I want deployment for test to be notified on one channel and prod on the other. Please help

Comment: Some more information about your current setup would be useful. 

I've got the following questions off of the top of my head: 
Are you using incoming slack webhooks to receive these messages?
What is your job configuration?
How does the job know what environment it is running in?
How are you planning to trigger the slack incoming webhook?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 

I am using webhooks for these messages, This is a freestyle project, The values(prod or test) will be sent as a  choice parameters. I am currently using slck-notification plugin to show these messages over the slack